# How to check credentials against botframework api

Tags: botframework

I'd like to check that my bot credentials (appId + appSecret) are ok to connect to https://api.botframework.com/bot/v1.0/messages.

I can't send a real message because i have no conversation running so I tried to post the following json message :
 `{ "type": "Ping"}` but the response i got was 
`{
  "error": {
    "message": "Expression evaluation failed. Object reference not set to an instance of an object.",
    "code": "ServiceError"
  }
}`

Is there any way to check if my access to the api is ok?

Comment: EDIT: My question was not precise enough: I'm asking how to do it programmatically.
Use case is : i have a website where a user can register his bot credentials and i want to check if his configuration is ok.

Answer (score 0):

If you've registered your bot, you can visit the [Bot Framework](https://dev.botframework.com/) page, click on the My Bots menu, and select your registered bot. On your bot page, scroll down to the bottom left and there's a test box.

Also, you can use the emulator. It has a place in the upper right corner to replace the default credentials with your bot credentials. Then change the URL to where you have your bot deployed. Tip: remember to append 'api/messages' to the URL.

Comment: Sorry my question was not precise enough: Do you know how to check programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

Download the [BotFrameworkEmulator](http://docs.botframework.com/connector/tools/bot-framework-emulator/#navtitle) to test connectivity to your bot. It works on windows and OSX if you have mono installed. You can change the default settings that the emulator uses by typing '/settings' after running it.  You will be prompted to enter your appId, appSecret and url endpoint for sending and receiving messages to/from your bot.

You can also use the [directline](http://docs.botframework.com/sdkreference/restapi-directline/#navtitle) rest api to initiate conversations and send messages to your bot

Comment: Sorry my question was not precise enough: Do you know how to check programmatically + I don't want to activate directline rest api